# How to detect rich edit content in C++

Tags: c++, windows, richtextbox, editcontrol, richedit-control

How could I detect whether an edit control support rich content in windows with `C++` code, for example, I could copy/paste an image into it.

Additionally, If I get the `HWND` of the foreground window, how could I get the edit control, but not the frame window?

Comment: The control types are different? Can you show some code you have tried?

Comment: Call `GetClassName()` to determine the window class of the control.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: *"The control types are different?"* - Yes, of course they are. But they are all referenced through the same opaque data type: `HWND`. As always, your contribution to a Windows-specific question is not at all helpful.